# gridmvc querying without lazyloading

Tags: c#

آere is my store class:

```
public class Store : IEntity, IAuditedEntity
{
    public Store();

    public double CommissionRate { get; set; }
    public bool CommissionEnabled { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<User> StoreUsers { get; set; }}
```

And here is my user class:

public class User : IdentityUser, IEntity
    {
        public User();

```
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustomerAppToken { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string StoreDeviceId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string CustomerDeviceId { get; set; }
    public bool StoreAppInstalled { get; set; }
    public bool WinAppInstalled { get; set; }
```

I want to show "yes" in a gridview column if any user of that store has `winappinstall = true` and here is my code for that:

```
 cols.Add("CustomerAppInstalled").WithHeaderText("HAs App?")
                                .WithValueExpression(p => p.OnlinePaymentEnabled.ToBoolean() ? "yes" : "no")
                                .WithVisibility(visible: true, allowChangeVisibility: true)
                                .WithSorting(true);
```

but it throws the exception of :

> the objectcontext instance has been disposed

My solution was to use .Include to disable lazyloading but I do not know where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turning off lazy loading for specific properties in your code, mark

```
public virtual ICollection<User> StoreUsers { get; set; }}
```

as

```
public ICollection<User> StoreUsers { get; set; }}
```

Lazy loading can be turned off for all entities in the context by setting a flag on the Configuration property to false. In you database context set the flag:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```